# Panic when trying to insert into table using golang

Tags: mysql, sqlite, go

I am trying to insert data to a database which I have created using `SQLite3`using go lang. The database has the name `mydb` and my table has the name artists and contains 3 cols

Here is my code:

```
package main

    import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"

        _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
        sqlite "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    )

    func main() {
        //create("testdb")
        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        defer db.Close()

        insert, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO artists (name,album,hits)values('x','y','z')")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        defer insert.Close()
        fmt.Println("connected")
    }
```

and Here is the error Im getting when i run `main.go`

```
  panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        C:/Users/HP/go/src/connectingToDb/main.go:20 +0x1e5
exit status 2
```

Please note that i have created the database in the same file as the main.go

Comment: You've mentioned `sqlite`, but then it's `mysql` in your code. Those are 2 distinct and not interchangeable technologies

Comment: There's insufficient information in this question to determine why the target machine is refusing the connection.

Answer (score 2):

You should open connect to sqlite like this:
`db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "my.db")`

Here is working code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "my.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    _, err = db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artists (`+
         ` id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,`+
         ` name text,`+
         ` album text,`+
         ` hits text`+
    `)`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    insert, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO artists (name,album,hits) VALUES('x','y','z')")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer insert.Close()
    fmt.Println("connected")
}
```